# What is the difference between the [debug] and [debugging] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The Magento.SE site has these two tags:

- [debug](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug)
- [debugging](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging)

Neither have usage guidance.

Is there a difference between the two? If so, let me know what the differences are and I'll add it to the usage guidance. Otherwise, I would like to retag all [debugging](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) questions with [debug](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debug), and then remove the [debugging](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) tag.